# MySQL GROUP BY "group" and order by largest ID

Tags: mysql

I have the following table: **Tree**. I am trying to select the highest Primary Key ID per **scenario_id**

```
id  user_id  scenario_id
----------------------------------
100   1        10
200   1        10
300   1        5
400   1        5
500   1        5


SELECT * FROM tree 
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY scenario_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

With my above query I don't get the largest ID. I get **300 and 100** -- But I want to get **200 and 500**.
Here is the table dump to test:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scenario_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tree` (`id`, `user_id`, `scenario_id`) VALUES
    (5, 1, 5),
    (100, 1, 10),
    (200, 1, 10),
    (300, 1, 5),
    (400, 1, 5),
    (500, 1, 5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggregate function to get a specific value for a group

```
SELECT scenario_id, max(id) as max_id
FROM tree 
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY scenario_id
```

Comment: Hm, an obtuse answer to start the ball rolling! ;-)

Comment: @JREAM: No, you should not mix selects of column in your group and the others. Always use aggregate functions on the other columns when you select them.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to keep your select * and avoid grouping to get these results from the same record you could also use a self join:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM 
tree t1 LEFT JOIN tree t2 ON t1.scenario_id = t2.scenario_id AND t2.id > t1.id
WHERE 
t2.id IS NULL;
```

Sometimes this can be useful to pull additional fields that you can't get as efficiently using a group by/aggregate solution.